# How does Return/Insertion loss work for wireless devices if there’s no cable?

Tags: rf, testing

I understand return loss is the ratio of how much signal is reflected in a transmission line. But for wireless devices there is no cable. So how is this measured?

So is the impedance mismatch for wireless devices between air and the antenna?

Comment: at the antenna port

Answer (score 1):

A transmission line can be a cable.

But a transmission line can also be **air** (or vacuum).

To get a signal (from a cable) into the air we would use an **antenna**.
The reverse is also true, to get a signal out of the air into a cable also
an antenna is used.

An antenna is basically the device that "connects" the cable to the air.

If this would all go perfectly (no or little losses) then all the signal from the cable ends up in the air (or vise-versa).

But if there is a **mismatch** than (part of) the signal will reflect, this is what your question is about.

This mismatch can be measured from the "cable side" of the antenna. Instead of connecting it to a transmitter or receiver, we connect it so a **network analyzer** or a **vector impedance analyzer**.

This is a device capable of making a plot of impedance over frequency, reflection coefficients (S-parameters, for your question it is S11). There are also network analyzers that can make a plot of the characteristic impedance as a function of the distance the signal has traveled. That can be used to find where a cable is broken but also where the mismatch is in a cable to antenna connection.

Here's an example of a plot of the characteristic impedance of as a function of the frequency. We can see that the system reflects the least at 871 MHz. At 871 MHz the of the 0 dBm input signal only -24.29 dBm reflects back. Obviously this system is to be used at 871 MHz!

[image]

Comment: There is already a lot of arguing about things like waveguides being transmission lines or not (and vice-versa). Calling free-space a transmission line does not seem correct?

Comment: OK, free space is different since the wave is not contained (as opposed to in cable or waveguide). Still the wave **travels** through free space like it does in a cable. If there is a better word to use for the "free space transmission line" I'd be happy to hear it :-)

Comment: Thanks. So is the impedance mismatch for wireless devices between air and the antenna?

Comment: That is one part of it, first the cable has to match to the electrical connection of the antenna. If both are say 50 ohms there's no problem. But if the antenna is 80 ohms a **matching network** must be used (usually just a couple of caps and inductors). Secondly, the antenna must of course be able to be efficient at interfacing (transmit/receive) the signal to the air. If you use a 1 GHz antenna at 800 MHz, this will never be optimum and also a source for reflections.

Comment: What are some tests to do so the antenna is transmitting/receiving the correct signals

Comment: As described in my answer, an S11 measurement as that indicates how well the antenna is matched to the transceiver. If matched well then it will receive/transmit correctly at the frequency it is matched at. If an "incorrect" signal is present at that frequency it will be received as the antenna cannot "filter out" wrong signals when they are at the "right" frequency. It is also possible to test the antenna + transceiver with a reference antenna and network analyzer in a Faraday cage (anechoic chamber) but it is more cumbersome.